# Preferred resource design in a REST API?

Tags: rest

Let's say I have a domain with customers that can "commit" (which is a use case in the domain). Is it preferable to include the actor (customer) explicitly in the resource like this:

```
POST /customers/{id}/commit
```

or would it be better to model the creation of a new commit like this:

```
POST /commitments
```

Does it matter and if so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the relationship between `customer` and `commitment`. A Rest-ful URI should be exposing a resource. If commitments make sense only in the customer context (or are a part of the customer) then an URI like this one is justified (it is the same as yours, the customer is the main resource, but note it is not using a verb, but noun, which is preferable):

```
POST /customers/{customer_id}/commitments
```

But if the resource is logically dependent on another resource (different than customer) or can also be used out of the context of customers (for example a box of commitments) or it can be used by itself, it would make more sense to design the URI around said resource e.g.:

```
POST /commitmentbox/commitments
```

or just

```
POST /commitments
```

I'd suggest the *Creating resources* section in this [blog post](http://blog.2partsmagic.com/restful-uri-design/). It discusses  multiple best practices in REST-ful URI design. Also see [this one](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html) where an even more complex scenario is discussed (`customer` makes `orders` that have `line items`). Both posts are very good.

Good luck!